# OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException when I try to click the button in expandable area

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, nunit, webdriverwait, expected-condition

I'm trying to write tests for https://www.booking.com/ just for my own experience. So, I faced a problem: I keep getting NoSuchElementException when trying to change number of guests in their form.

```
Message: OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException : no such element: Unable to locate element: 
{"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="xp__guests__inputs - container"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/button[2]"}
  (Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.88)
```

I've already tried any of suggestions on SOF:

`driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120);`

and `new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(200)).Until(condition: ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"xp__guests__inputs - container\"]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/button[2]")));`

and tried to use XPath Axes to access element I need

All these strategies don't seem to work for me.

My code:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using System;

namespace Tests
{
    public class Tests
    {
        IWebDriver driver;

        [SetUp]
        public void StartBrowser()
        {
            driver = new ChromeDriver("D:\\Development\\chromedriver_win32");
            //driver.Url = "https://www.booking.com/";
        }
        [Test]
        public void TestAccomodation()
        {
            driver.Url = "https://www.booking.com/";
            IWebElement cityTextbox = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"ss\"]"));
            cityTextbox.SendKeys("Осака");
            IWebElement accomodationDate = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"frm\"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div"));
            accomodationDate.Click();

            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
            IWebElement accArival = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"frm\"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]"));
            accArival.Click();

            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
            IWebElement accDeparture = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"frm\"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]"));
            accDeparture.Click();


            IWebElement partyMembers = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"frm\"]/div[1]/div[3]"));
            partyMembers.Click();


            //IWebElement container = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//**[@id=\"frm\"]/div[1]/div[3]/div")); //ERROR!

            IWebElement partyChildren = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"xp__guests__inputs - container\"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/button[2]")); //ERROR!
            partyChildren.Click();
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void CloseBrowser()
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            driver.Close();
        }

    }
}
```

Code that I'm testing:

```
<div id="xp__guests__inputs-container" class="xp__guests__inputs focussable " data-group-modal="" role="region" aria-label="Число номеров и гостей" style="display: block;">
<div data-component="search/group/group" data-sb-id="main" data-sb-width="medium" data-sb-bbtool-searchbox="0" data-sb-group-children-hide="0" data-sb-group-children-ages-hide="0" data-sb-group-infants-hide="1" data-sb-group-pets-hide="0" data-sb-group-rooms-hide="0" data-sb-group-block-labels="0" data-sb-group-use_adults_label="0" data-sb-group-always-expanded="0" data-sb-group-use-bui-stepper="1" data-sb-group-bui-steppers-accessible="1" data-fe_sb_group_descriptive_dropdowns="0" data-fe_sb_universal_design="0" data-fe_sb_xpi="1" data-fe_remove_duplicate_ids="0" data-fe_sb_unique_id="" data-sb_reorder_rooms_block="1">
<div class="u-clearfix" data-render="">






    <div class="sb-group__field sb-group__field-adults">




  <div class="bui-stepper" data-bui-component="InputStepper">
    <div class="bui-stepper__title-wrapper">
      <label class="bui-stepper__title" for="group_adults">Взрослых</label>

    </div>

      <div class="bui-stepper__wrapper sb-group__stepper-a11y">
        <input style="display: none" type="number" class="bui-stepper__input" data-bui-ref="input-stepper-field" id="group_adults" name="group_adults" min="1" max="30" value="2" data-group-adults-count="">
        <button class="bui-button bui-button--secondary bui-stepper__subtract-button " data-bui-ref="input-stepper-subtract-button" type="button" aria-label="Взрослых: уменьшить количество" aria-describedby="group_adults_desc">
          <span class="bui-button__text">−</span>
        </button>
        <span class="bui-stepper__display" data-bui-ref="input-stepper-value" aria-hidden="true">2</span>
        <button class="bui-button bui-button--secondary bui-stepper__add-button " data-bui-ref="input-stepper-add-button" type="button" aria-label="Взрослых: увеличить количество" aria-describedby="group_adults_desc">
          <span class="bui-button__text">+</span>
        </button>
        <span class="bui-u-sr-only" aria-live="assertive" id="group_adults_desc">2 Взрослых</span>
      </div>

  </div>


    </div>




      <div class="sb-group__field sb-group-children ">




  <div class="bui-stepper" data-bui-component="InputStepper">
    <div class="bui-stepper__title-wrapper">
      <label class="bui-stepper__title" for="group_children">Детей</label>

    </div>

      <div class="bui-stepper__wrapper sb-group__stepper-a11y">
        <input style="display: none" type="number" class="bui-stepper__input" data-bui-ref="input-stepper-field" id="group_children" name="group_children" min="0" max="10" value="0" data-group-children-count="">
        <button class="bui-button bui-button--secondary bui-stepper__subtract-button sb-group__stepper-button-disabled" data-bui-ref="input-stepper-subtract-button" type="button" aria-label="Детей: уменьшить количество" aria-describedby="group_children_desc">
          <span class="bui-button__text">−</span>
        </button>
        <span class="bui-stepper__display" data-bui-ref="input-stepper-value" aria-hidden="true">0</span>
        <button class="bui-button bui-button--secondary bui-stepper__add-button " data-bui-ref="input-stepper-add-button" type="button" aria-label="Детей: увеличить количество" aria-describedby="group_children_desc">
          <span class="bui-button__text">+</span>
        </button>
        <span class="bui-u-sr-only" aria-live="assertive" id="group_children_desc">0 Детей</span>
      </div>

  </div>




    </div>







    <div class="sb-group__field sb-group__field-rooms">


  <div class="bui-stepper" data-bui-component="InputStepper">
    <div class="bui-stepper__title-wrapper">
      <label class="bui-stepper__title" for="no_rooms">Номера</label>

    </div>

      <div class="bui-stepper__wrapper sb-group__stepper-a11y">
        <input style="display: none" type="number" class="bui-stepper__input" data-bui-ref="input-stepper-field" id="no_rooms" name="no_rooms" min="1" max="30" value="1" data-group-rooms-count="">
        <button class="bui-button bui-button--secondary bui-stepper__subtract-button sb-group__stepper-button-disabled" data-bui-ref="input-stepper-subtract-button" type="button" aria-label="Номера: уменьшить количество" aria-describedby="no_rooms_desc">
          <span class="bui-button__text">−</span>
        </button>
        <span class="bui-stepper__display" data-bui-ref="input-stepper-value" aria-hidden="true">1</span>
        <button class="bui-button bui-button--secondary bui-stepper__add-button " data-bui-ref="input-stepper-add-button" type="button" aria-label="Номера: увеличить количество" aria-describedby="no_rooms_desc">
          <span class="bui-button__text">+</span>
        </button>
        <span class="bui-u-sr-only" aria-live="assertive" id="no_rooms_desc">1 Номера</span>
      </div>

  </div>

    </div>


















</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any element with id="xp__guests__inputs - container" and the xpath which you are testing is correct. Also, try to relative paths with xpath functions rather than hardcoding indexes.

Comment: @Abhinav I've edited the HTML-code I'm testing. Now you can see element with such ID.
About xpath functions (e.g. axes): I've written that I've already tried to use them but kept getting NoSuchElementException.

Comment: Is this element inside any frame?

Comment: @Abhinav nope, or I don't see any.

Comment: Moreover all other code works completely perfect despite performing actions in the same HTML-block.

Comment: Ok, so I found the answer just right now. More likely, it's (how we say in russian) a 'dog-nail' but whatever.

The answer was to get not the shortened XPath and not XPath formed with functions but the full one. For example:

`//*[@id=\"xp__guests__inputs-container\"]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/button[2]` - WRONG

`/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/button[2]` - RIGHT

P.S.: I have no freackin' idea why it's working but it is.

P.P.S.: Should I put it as an answer? Maybe we need some explanation around there?

Comment: Relative xpath should work. I have never faced any issue with relative xpath. I have always avoided using absolute xpath whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set number of guests in the form of https://www.booking.com/ as **Adults** as **`3`**, **Children** as **`2`** and **Rooms** as **`2`** you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `ElementToBeClickable()` and you can use the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  ```
  driver.Url = "https://www.booking.com/";
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("label.xp__input#xp__guests__toggle"))).Click();
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("button[aria-label='Increase number of Adults']"))).Click();
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("button[aria-label='Increase number of Children']"))).Click();
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("button[aria-label='Increase number of Children']"))).Click();
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("button[aria-label='Increase number of Rooms']"))).Click();
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: booking_dot_com]